# Python: Counting words from a directory of txt files and writing word counts to a separate txt file

Tags: python, counter, sys, txt

New to Python and I'm trying to count the words in a directory of text files and write the output to a separate text file. However, I want to specify conditions. So if word count is > 0 is would like to write the count and file path to one file and if the count is == 0. I would like to write the count and file path to a separate file. Below is my code so far. I think I'm close, but I'm hung up on how to do the conditions and separate files. Thanks.

```
import sys
import os
from collections import Counter
import glob

stdoutOrigin=sys.stdout 
sys.stdout = open("log.txt", "w")
              
def count_words_in_dir(dirpath, words, action=None):
    for filepath in glob.iglob(os.path.join("path", '*.txt')):
        with open(filepath) as f:
            data = f.read()
            for key,val in words.items():
            #print("key is " + key + "\n")
                ct = data.count(key)
                words[key] = ct
            if action:
                 action(filepath, words)
            
                
                


def print_summary(filepath, words):
    for key,val in sorted(words.items()):
        print(filepath)
        if val > 0:
            print('{0}:\t{1}'.format(
            key,
            val))
        







filepath = sys.argv[1]
keys = ["x", "y"]
words = dict.fromkeys(keys,0)

count_words_in_dir(filepath, words, action=print_summary)

sys.stdout.close()
sys.stdout=stdoutOrigin
```

Comment: `stdoutOrigin=sys.stdout` and `sys.stdout = open("log.txt", "w")` why on earth would you monkey_patch this instead of using a file logger??? or just open the output file and write into it directly !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly urge you to not repurpose `stdout` for writing data to a file as part of the normal course of your program.  I also wonder how you can ever have a word "count < 0".  I assume you meant "count == 0".

The main problem that your code has is in this line:

```
for filepath in glob.iglob(os.path.join("path", '*.txt')):
```

The string constant `"path"` I'm pretty sure doesn't belong there.  I think you want `filepath` there instead. I would think that this problem would prevent your code from working at all.

Here's a version of your code where I fixed these issues and added the logic to write to two different output files based on the count:

```
import sys
import os
import glob

out1 = open("/tmp/so/seen.txt", "w")
out2 = open("/tmp/so/missing.txt", "w")

def count_words_in_dir(dirpath, words, action=None):
    for filepath in glob.iglob(os.path.join(dirpath, '*.txt')):
        with open(filepath) as f:
            data = f.read()
            for key, val in words.items():
                # print("key is " + key + "\n")
                ct = data.count(key)
                words[key] = ct
            if action:
                action(filepath, words)


def print_summary(filepath, words):
    for key, val in sorted(words.items()):
        whichout = out1 if val > 0 else out2
        print(filepath, file=whichout)
        print('{0}: {1}'.format(key, val), file=whichout)

filepath = sys.argv[1]
keys = ["country", "friend", "turnip"]
words = dict.fromkeys(keys, 0)

count_words_in_dir(filepath, words, action=print_summary)

out1.close()
out2.close()
```

Result:

file seen.txt:

```
/Users/steve/tmp/so/dir/data2.txt
friend: 1
/Users/steve/tmp/so/dir/data.txt
country: 2
/Users/steve/tmp/so/dir/data.txt
friend: 1
```

file missing.txt:

```
/Users/steve/tmp/so/dir/data2.txt
country: 0
/Users/steve/tmp/so/dir/data2.txt
turnip: 0
/Users/steve/tmp/so/dir/data.txt
turnip: 0
```

(excuse me for using some search words that were a bit more interesting than yours)

Comment: That's great. Thanks. It should have been == 0, but I did do a great job of copyediting, and the same goes for the "path" constant. But this works great. Thanks for the very helpful comment,

Answer (score 1):

Hello I hope I understood your question correctly, this code will count how many different words are in your file and depending on the conditions will do something you want.

```
import os
all_words = {}


def count(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as f:
        # for better performance it is a good idea to go line by line through file
        for line in f:
            # singles out all the words, by splitting string around spaces
            words = line.split(" ")
            # and checks if word already exists in all_words dictionary...
            for word in words:
                try:
                    # ...if it does increment number of repetitions
                    all_words[word.replace(",", "").replace(".", "").lower()] += 1
                except Exception:
                    # ...if it doesn't create it and give it number of repetitions 1
                    all_words[word.replace(",", "").replace(".", "").lower()] = 1


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # for every text file in your current directory count how many words it has
    for file in os.listdir("."):
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            all_words = {}
            count(file)
            n = len(all_words)
            # depending on the number of words do something
            if n > 0:
                with open("count1.txt", "a") as f:
                    f.write(file + "\n" + str(n) + "\n")
            else:
                with open("count2.txt", "a") as f:
                    f.write(file + "\n" + str(n) + "\n")
```

if you want to count same word multiple times you can add up all values from dictionary or you can eliminate try-except block and count every word there.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this out.